# Why does order matter in constant buffers?

Tags: directx11, hlsl

I have a rather peculiar question remaining after solving most of [my own question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53345125/why-does-order-matter-in-shaders). When creating the constant buffers used by my shaders, I've learned that the order of variables between the `cbuffer` and the `struct` representing it have to be an accurate match. I am still unsure as to why this is such an issue, and that's why I'm here.

When creating a `cbuffer` to hold object data, I create the `cbuffer` and `struct` like so:

```
cbuffer ObjectBuffer : register(b0) {
    float4x4 World;
    float4x4 WorldViewProjection;
    float4x4 WorldInverseTranspose;
}
public struct ObjectBuffer {
    public Matrix World;
    public Matrix WorldViewProjection;
    public Matrix WorldInverseTranspose;
}
```

This way works just fine, but if I reorder the `cbuffer` variables, or the `struct` variables and do not reflect the changes in the other, issues arise and I can't even create the buffer.

```
cbuffer ObjectBuffer : register(b0) {
    float4x4 WorldInverseTranspose;
    float4x4 WorldViewProjection;
    float4x4 World;
}
public struct ObjectBuffer {
    public Matrix World;
    public Matrix WorldViewProjection;
    public Matrix WorldInverseTranspose;
}
```

---

In this case, the types are exactly the same and given the fact that `HLSL` expects constant buffers to be in 16 byte chunks; why does the ordering matter so much?

Aren't `float4x4` types the same as `Matrix` types where it's essentially an array of arrays?

```
[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] = 16 bytes
[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] = 16 bytes
[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] = 16 bytes
[ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] = 16 bytes
[    TOTAL   ] = 64 bytes
```

Since a `float` is 4 bytes on its own, this would mean a `float4` is 16 bytes, and thus a `float4x4` is 64 bytes. So why does the order matter if the size remained the same?

---

### Update

So I've re-visited the issue and turns out I was wrong about the issue given above. This does allow the objects to be compiled correctly but presents grotesque effects in the shaders since the variables are in the wrong order which is expected.

However, this issue came up because I misread which buffer was causing the issue initially. It was all related to my material buffer in which I have a `bool` and a `float`. When I swapped the two on either side without reflecting the changes in the other it failed to create. I presume this is due to the difference in expected types. The `cbuffer` is in `bool-float` order while the `struct` is the opposite. This I expect to cause an issue, but it would still be nice to know what's happening under the hood to cause it to break. Is it because `bool` is a single byte but perhaps allocated into a chunk of 4 bytes?

Comment: Your edit to point out that you're seeing errors at creation is useful, but it would help to then see _how_ you are creating the buffer and what the actual error you get is (e.g., from the debug layer of the runtime). The ordering issues _are_ problems, but they shouldn't normally prevent creation of the buffer since the creation of the buffer doesn't depend on the format of the data inside in general (but might depending on what C# wrapper method you are using?)

Answer (score 1):

DirectX doesn't see your `struct`. When you set the uniform buffer all it sees is a bunch of bytes that it needs to map to the `cbuffer` definition in the shader. This is also why you may need to add padding between subsequent fields when alignments between the host language (C/C++/C#/etc.) and hlsl don't match. In particular when dealing with multi-float variables.

In effect it does a `reintepret_cast` on your `struct` to the one declared in the shader.

If the layout does not match then you get surprising behavior.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on this? Is this occurring when it creates the actual buffer object? Why does this matter if the types are exactly the same with no padding needed? I would expect incorrect behavior during rendering but not prior to that. For example if I have four `float` types that do different things, and I reorder them, they are all still floats, but now the behavior of the `HLSL` will change, but it should still create the buffer just fine.